# Consume rxjs observable in a regular express.js middleware

Tags: express, rxjs, observable, middleware

i'm struggling with RxJS which unfortunately is in use in my project.
I have an observable `getSettings(req)` which i'd like to use in a regular express.js middleware, something like that:

```
middleware(req, res, next) {
  ...
  const settings = getSettings(req);
  ...
  // do something with settings
  ...
  next();
}
```

Usually that observable is used in `switchMap` / `observableForkJoin`, so in a standard rxjs way, but never directly in the regular middleware.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

seems to work fine with

```
const settings = await getSettings(req).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more rx idomatic way could be

```
middleware(req, res, next) {
  ...
  // perform some actions when the getSettings Observable emits piping
  // some operators into the Observable
  getSettings(req).pipe(
    // use the tap operator to perform side effects
    tap(setting => {
       ...
       // do something with settings
       ...
       // when finished with the side effects call next
       next()
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: yeah that is nice for side effects, but in my case i need to have the result of getSetting() and use it ehmm unpiped :)

Comment: Are you sure that `const settings = await getSettings(req).toPromise();` is different from the `pipe`/`tap` solution? I think they are basically the same thing since `await` blocks the execution until the promise is resolved and then calls `next`, which is what my solution does, unless I have misunderstood something.

Comment: i'm not saying your solution is not working, i'm pretty sure it will work fine, it just require all the code that i mentioned as //do-something to be put in the pipe codeblock, and in my case it's like 200 lines which i don't want to touch.